# Paste Image into Photoshop to auto fit within the background layer

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images, photo-editing, image-editing

I found the image from the net, I copy it to my clipboard, and paste it into my Photoshop

It look like this

[image]

After I manually shrink down then it look this

[image]

Is there a special paste that will look like this ?

I'm wondering if there is a way to paste into Photoshop to auto fit the image within the background.

---

## Questions

**How would one go about and do something like this ?**

---

I'm open to any suggestions at this moment.

Any hints/suggestions / helps on this be will be much appreciated!

Comment: As far as I'm aware for *pasting*, no. There's no automatic sizing option. The image is pasted to match the resolution of the document being pasted into.

Comment: I kind of remember I use to be able to do that.

Comment: I think you're thinking of the `Resize Image During Place` setting I mention in [my answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/121706/2332). Danielillo's answer relies on this setting by the way.

Answer (score 2):

There's a trick to do that.

- Copy the image you want to paste
- Instead of pasting in an open document, create a new one, this new document will have the copied image size
- Paste, save and close this document
- Go to your original document
- Menu File → Place Embedded: place the saved document with the pasted image

The embedded file will fit in the original document size.

Comment: Works, but I'm unsure if saving a file and placing it, then deleting the file later, is any faster or better than merely hitting Command-T, Command-Shift-O, Holding Option/Alt and scaling. The shortcut commands take milliseconds and don't litter a hard drive with unused files.

Answer (score 2):

This behavior does sort of exist, but it doesn't work in this scenario. There's this setting: `Preferences > General: Resize Image During Place` <sub><sup>(Cmd+K)</sup></sub>. This setting doesn't do anything on paste unless you paste in vector graphics. Well, that's a little misleading... You can paste in raster images this way if you copy them from Illustrator (It wraps the raster image inside an SVG and that invokes the paste as dialog in PS). I believe that is the only way to paste in raster images so that they honor that setting.

---

I happen to have made a script that sorta does this: [Paste or Place Inside Selection.jsx](https://github.com/joonaspaakko/paste-or-place-inside-selection-photoshop-script). The link leads to github that has a list of known issues. The script was written for Photoshop CC, so if you have an older PS it might not work with it.

**Usage**

You got 2 starting points...

- **[Selection method (gif)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpHss.gif):** If you have an active marquee selection in the document, the image is placed inside the selection on a new layer.
- **[Active layer method (gif)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUiB5.gif):** ...otherwise the image is placed in a new layer and placed in a clipping mask with the active layer.

  - If you want to place inside an existing clipping mask, you can select any layer that is part of that clipping mask. The new image will be placed on top of that stack.

There is one caveat you might care about: Right now the active layer method doesn't work with the background layer if it's locked. There's no reason why it couldn't be made to work, but since I can unlock the bg layer before running the script or make a selection covering the whole document Cmd+A... it hasn't really felt like an important addition.

Here's the code for safekeeping:

```
// Paste or Place Inside Selection.jsx
// Version: 0.2.
// https://github.com/joonaspaakko/paste-or-place-inside-selection-photoshop-script

// Changelog:

// ********* V.0.2. *********
// - Tested in PS CC 2019
// - Renewed dialog. Numbers from 1 to 4 can be used as shortcuts.
// - Spacebar used to trigger paste and enter used to trigger place, but now it's reversed.
// - Name changed from "Place Inside Selection.jsx" to "Paste or Place Inside Selection.jsx"

// ********* V.0.1. *********
// - First version
// - Written for PS CC 2018
// - Images are placed as Smart Objects and resized to the size of your selection.
// - Does not respect the original size of your image in the sense that if you place your image into a selection that is bigger than the image, it will ruthlessly upsize it the size of the selection.

var method = null;
var fit_or_fill = null;
var clipboardEmpty = false;
var hasSelection = selectionExists();
var tempChannelName = 'Temp Channel - 0123456789';

// Writes one history state....
app.activeDocument.suspendHistory("Place Inside Selection.jsx", "init()");

function init() {

  // Place options
  dialog();


  // Don't continue if user cancelled using ESC
  if ( method != null ) {

    var image;

    // If PLACE was the chosen method, open up "browse" dialog to find a file to place.
    if ( method === 'place' ) {
      image = File.openDialog( 'Open input image...' );
    }
    // If PASTE was the chosen method, test clipboard...
    else {
      image = "clipboard";
      clipboardEmpty = testClipboard();
    }

    // Don't continue if user cancels the "browse" dialog or if the clipboard is empty
    if ( image != null && !clipboardEmpty ) {
      main( image );
    }
    else {
      alert( 'Paste failed \nMake sure you have an image in your clipboard and try again...' );
    }

  }

} // init();

function main( image ) {

  var doc = app.activeDocument,
            activeLayer = doc.activeLayer,
      rulerUnits = app.preferences.rulerUnits;

  app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;

  // Could be a layer or a selection
  var target = getTargetBounds( doc, activeLayer );

  if ( hasSelection ) {
    saveSelection( doc );
  }

  if ( image === "clipboard" ) {
    pasteIMG( doc, activeLayer, image, target.width, target.height );
  }
  else {
    placeIMG( doc, activeLayer, image, target.width, target.height );
  }

  resizeIMG( doc.activeLayer, target.width, target.height );
  // align( [layerToAlign], [targetBounds] );
  align( doc.activeLayer, target.bounds );

  // Wrap it up....
  // When there is a selection, we add a Layer Mask to the image.
  if ( hasSelection ) {

    loadSelection( doc );

    // Add Layers Mask
    // =======================================================
    var idMk = charIDToTypeID( "Mk  " );
        var desc437 = new ActionDescriptor();
        var idNw = charIDToTypeID( "Nw  " );
        var idChnl = charIDToTypeID( "Chnl" );
        desc437.putClass( idNw, idChnl );
        var idAt = charIDToTypeID( "At  " );
            var ref249 = new ActionReference();
            var idChnl = charIDToTypeID( "Chnl" );
            var idChnl = charIDToTypeID( "Chnl" );
            var idMsk = charIDToTypeID( "Msk " );
            ref249.putEnumerated( idChnl, idChnl, idMsk );
        desc437.putReference( idAt, ref249 );
        var idUsng = charIDToTypeID( "Usng" );
        var idUsrM = charIDToTypeID( "UsrM" );
        var idRvlS = charIDToTypeID( "RvlS" );
        desc437.putEnumerated( idUsng, idUsrM, idRvlS );
    executeAction( idMk, desc437, DialogModes.NO );

  }
  // When there is no selection, a clipping mask is used and both layers are selected.
  else {
    // When there aren't any existing layers in a clipping mask:
    if ( !doc.activeLayer.grouped ) doc.activeLayer.grouped = true;
  }

  // Reset ruler units
  app.preferences.rulerUnits = rulerUnits;

} // main();

function loadSelection( doc ) {
    doc.selection.load( doc.channels[ tempChannelName ], SelectionType.REPLACE );
  doc.channels[ tempChannelName ].remove();
}

function saveSelection( doc ) {
    var channels = doc.channels;
  var tempChannel = channels.add();
    tempChannel.kind = ChannelType.SELECTEDAREA;
    tempChannel.name = tempChannelName;
    doc.selection.store( channels[ tempChannelName ], SelectionType.REPLACE );
  // Reselects RGB channels
  doc.activeChannels = [ channels["Red"], channels["Green"], channels["Blue"] ];
  doc.selection.deselect();
}

function testClipboard() {

  var cEmpty = false,
      tempDoc = app.documents.add();

  try {

    // Paste
    // =======================================================
    var idpast = charIDToTypeID( "past" );
        var desc1408 = new ActionDescriptor();
        var idAntA = charIDToTypeID( "AntA" );
        var idAnnt = charIDToTypeID( "Annt" );
        var idAnno = charIDToTypeID( "Anno" );
        desc1408.putEnumerated( idAntA, idAnnt, idAnno );
        var idAs = charIDToTypeID( "As  " );
        var idPxel = charIDToTypeID( "Pxel" );
        desc1408.putClass( idAs, idPxel );
    executeAction( idpast, desc1408, DialogModes.NO );

  } catch(e) { cEmpty = true; }

  tempDoc.close( SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES );

  return cEmpty;

}

function pasteIMG( doc, activeLayer, image ) {

  // Paste
  // =======================================================
  var idpast = charIDToTypeID( "past" );
      var desc1408 = new ActionDescriptor();
      var idAntA = charIDToTypeID( "AntA" );
      var idAnnt = charIDToTypeID( "Annt" );
      var idAnno = charIDToTypeID( "Anno" );
      desc1408.putEnumerated( idAntA, idAnnt, idAnno );
      var idAs = charIDToTypeID( "As  " );
      var idPxel = charIDToTypeID( "Pxel" );
      desc1408.putClass( idAs, idPxel );
  executeAction( idpast, desc1408, DialogModes.NO );

  // Convert pasted image into a Smart Object
  var idnewPlacedLayer = stringIDToTypeID( "newPlacedLayer" );
  executeAction( idnewPlacedLayer, undefined, DialogModes.NO );
  doc.activeLayer.name = "[Pasted Image]";

}

function placeIMG( doc, activeLayer, image ) {

  // =======================================================
  var idPlc = charIDToTypeID( "Plc " );
      var desc637 = new ActionDescriptor();
      var idIdnt = charIDToTypeID( "Idnt" );
      desc637.putInteger( idIdnt, 62 );
      var idnull = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
      desc637.putPath( idnull, new File( image ) );
      var idFTcs = charIDToTypeID( "FTcs" );
      var idQCSt = charIDToTypeID( "QCSt" );
      var idQcsa = charIDToTypeID( "Qcsa" );
      desc637.putEnumerated( idFTcs, idQCSt, idQcsa );
      var idOfst = charIDToTypeID( "Ofst" );
          var desc638 = new ActionDescriptor();
          var idHrzn = charIDToTypeID( "Hrzn" );
          var idPxl = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
          desc638.putUnitDouble( idHrzn, idPxl, 0.000000 );
          var idVrtc = charIDToTypeID( "Vrtc" );
          var idPxl = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
          desc638.putUnitDouble( idVrtc, idPxl, -0.000000 );
      var idOfst = charIDToTypeID( "Ofst" );
      desc637.putObject( idOfst, idOfst, desc638 );
  executeAction( idPlc, desc637, DialogModes.NO );

}

function resizeIMG( imageLayer, target_width, target_height ) {

  // Small padding to help with anti-aliasing
  target_width = target_width + 2;
  target_height = target_height + 2;

  // Round 1#
  var bounds = imageLayer.boundsNoEffects;
  var image_width = bounds[2].value - bounds[0].value;
  var image_height = bounds[3].value - bounds[1].value;
  var newSize = (100 / image_width) * target_width;
  imageLayer.resize( newSize, newSize, AnchorPosition.MIDDLECENTER );

  // Round 2# ...if it is needed
  var bounds = imageLayer.boundsNoEffects;
  var image_width = bounds[2].value - bounds[0].value;
  var image_height = bounds[3].value - bounds[1].value;

  if (
    (fit_or_fill === 'fill' && image_height < target_height) ||
    (fit_or_fill === 'fit' && image_height > target_height)
  ) {
    var newSize = (target_height / image_height) * 100;
    imageLayer.resize( newSize, newSize, AnchorPosition.MIDDLECENTER );
  }

}

function getTargetBounds( doc, activeLayer ) {

    // Set selection as false, if bounds are not found.
    var bounds;
    if ( hasSelection ) {
        bounds = doc.selection.bounds;
    }
    else {
    var clippingMaskBase = findClippingMask( doc, activeLayer );
    // var clippingMaskBase = addToClippingMask( doc, activeLayer );
    if ( clippingMaskBase !== false ) {
      bounds = clippingMaskBase.boundsNoEffects;
    }
    else {
      bounds = activeLayer.boundsNoEffects;
    }
    }

    var width = bounds[2].value - bounds[0].value;
    var height = bounds[3].value - bounds[1].value;

    return {
    bounds: bounds,
    width: bounds[2].value - bounds[0].value,
    height: bounds[3].value - bounds[1].value,
  };

}

function align( imageLayer, targetBounds ) {

  var imageBounds = imageLayer.boundsNoEffects;

  var image = {
    offset: {
      top: imageBounds[1].value,
      right: imageBounds[2].value,
      bottom: imageBounds[3].value,
      left: imageBounds[0].value,
    },
  };
  var target = {
    offset: {
      top: targetBounds[1].value,
      right: targetBounds[2].value,
      bottom: targetBounds[3].value,
      left: targetBounds[0].value,
    },
  };

  var image_width = image.offset.right - image.offset.left;
  var image_height = image.offset.bottom - image.offset.top;

  var target_width = target.offset.right - target.offset.left;
  var target_height = target.offset.bottom - target.offset.top;

  var translateX = target.offset.left - image.offset.left - ( image_width/2 ) + ( target_width/2 );
  var translateY = target.offset.top - image.offset.top - ( image_height/2 ) + ( target_height/2 );
  imageLayer.translate( translateX, translateY );

}

function selectionExists() {

    var selection = false;
    try { selection = app.activeDocument.selection.bounds; } catch(e) {}

    return selection;

}

// Returns the base layer in a clipping mask
function findClippingMask( doc, layer ) {

  // Layer is in a clipping mask...
    if ( layer.grouped ) {

        while ( doc.activeLayer.grouped ) {
      selectLayer('below');
    }
        var clippingMaskBase = doc.activeLayer;

    app.runMenuItem( stringIDToTypeID('groupLayersEvent') );
    var tempGroup = doc.activeLayer;
    var newLayer = doc.artLayers.add();
    newLayer.move( tempGroup, ElementPlacement.INSIDE);
    newLayer.grouped = true;
    doc.activeLayer = tempGroup;
        app.runMenuItem( stringIDToTypeID('ungroupLayersEvent') );
    doc.activeLayer = newLayer;

    return clippingMaskBase;

    }
  // Layer is not in a clipping mask... but it could still be the base layer of a clipping mask
    else if ( !layer.grouped ) {

    app.runMenuItem( stringIDToTypeID('groupLayersEvent') );

        var tempGroup = doc.activeLayer,
                tempGroupLayers = tempGroup.layers,
                tempGroupLayersLength = tempGroupLayers.length;

    // When you group clipping mask base layer, it groups all the layers in that clipping mask.
    // So if the newly created group has more than one layer, the first active layer or the first layer of that group is the base layer.
        if ( tempGroupLayersLength > 1 ) {
            var clippingMaskBase = tempGroupLayers[ tempGroupLayersLength - 1 ];
            var newLayer = doc.artLayers.add();
            newLayer.move( tempGroup, ElementPlacement.INSIDE);
      newLayer.grouped = true;
      doc.activeLayer = tempGroup;
            app.runMenuItem( stringIDToTypeID('ungroupLayersEvent') );
            doc.activeLayer = newLayer;

            return clippingMaskBase;

        }
    // False alarm... No clipping masks here.
        else {
            app.runMenuItem( stringIDToTypeID('ungroupLayersEvent') );
            return false;
        }

    }

}

function selectLayer( direction ) {

  direction = charIDToTypeID( direction === 'above' ? "Frwr" : "Bckw" );

  try {
    // =======================================================
    var idslct = charIDToTypeID( "slct" );
    var desc4110 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idnull = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
    var ref750 = new ActionReference();
    var idLyr = charIDToTypeID( "Lyr " );
    var idOrdn = charIDToTypeID( "Ordn" );
    ref750.putEnumerated( idLyr, idOrdn, direction );
    desc4110.putReference( idnull, ref750 );
    var idMkVs = charIDToTypeID( "MkVs" );
    desc4110.putBoolean( idMkVs, false );
    var idLyrI = charIDToTypeID( "LyrI" );
    var list325 = new ActionList();
    list325.putInteger( 22 );
    desc4110.putList( idLyrI, list325 );
    executeAction( idslct, desc4110, DialogModes.NO );
  } catch (e) {}

}

function dialog() {

    /*
    Code for Import https://scriptui.joonas.me — (Triple click to select):
    {"items":{"item-0":{"id":0,"type":"Dialog","parentId":false,"style":{"text":"Paste or place inside selection.jsx","preferredSize":[0,0],"margins":24,"orientation":"column","spacing":10,"alignChildren":["center","top"]}},"item-1":{"id":1,"type":"Button","parentId":0,"style":{"text":"2. Paste / Fit","justify":"center","preferredSize":[0,0],"alignment":null}},"item-2":{"id":2,"type":"Button","parentId":0,"style":{"text":"1. Paste / Fill","justify":"center","preferredSize":[0,0],"alignment":null}},"item-3":{"id":3,"type":"Divider","parentId":0,"style":false},"item-4":{"id":4,"type":"Button","parentId":0,"style":{"text":"3. Place / Fill","justify":"center","preferredSize":[0,0],"alignment":null}},"item-5":{"id":5,"type":"Button","parentId":0,"style":{"text":"4. Place / Fit","justify":"center","preferredSize":[0,0],"alignment":null}}},"order":[0,2,1,3,4,5],"activeId":1}
    */

    // DIALOG
    // ======
    var dialog = new Window("dialog");
        dialog.text = "Paste or place inside selection.jsx";
        dialog.orientation = "column";
        dialog.alignChildren = ["center","top"];
        dialog.spacing = 10;
        dialog.margins = 24;

    var button1 = dialog.add("button", undefined, 'pasteFill', {name: "ok"});
        button1.text = "1. Paste / Fill";
        button1.justify = "center";

    var button2 = dialog.add("button", undefined, 'pasteFit', {name: "ok1"});
        button2.text = "2. Paste / Fit";
        button2.justify = "center";

    var divider1 = dialog.add("panel");
        divider1.alignment = "fill";

    var button3 = dialog.add("button", undefined, 'placeFill', {name: "ok3"});
        button3.text = "3. Place / Fill";
        button3.justify = "center";
      button3.active = true;

    var button4 = dialog.add("button", undefined, 'placeFit', {name: "ok4"});
        button4.text = "4. Place / Fit";
        button4.justify = "center";

    // CUSTOM EVENTS
  dialog.addEventListener ("keyup", function( key ) {
    if ( key.keyName == 1 ) {
      button1.onClick();
    }
    else if ( key.keyName == 2 ) {
      button2.onClick();
    }
    else if ( key.keyName == 3 ) {
      button3.onClick();
    }
    else if ( key.keyName == 4 ) {
      button4.onClick();
    }
  });

  // PASTE FILL
  button1.onClick = function () {
    method = 'paste';
    fit_or_fill = 'fill';
    dialog.close();
  }
  // PASTE FIT
  button2.onClick = function () {
    method = 'paste';
    fit_or_fill = 'fit';
    dialog.close();
  }
  // PLACE FILL
  button3.onClick = function () {
    method = 'place';
    fit_or_fill = 'fill';
    dialog.close();
  }
  // PLACE FILL
  button4.onClick = function () {
    method = 'place';
    fit_or_fill = 'fit';
    dialog.close();
  }

  dialog.show();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, no tricks. the fastest way to resize the image:

- <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste it in the center
- <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to resize
- drag holding <kbd>ALT</kbd> to keep the aspect ratio (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> for older PS versions) until it has the size you want.